# Relationship between maximum and supremum in a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

I have a question about lecture notes on Donsker's theorem Davar Khoshnevisan from this page [https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Edavar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf)

On the page 4 there is a equality:
$ \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \mathscr{S}_n(t) = \max_{0 \leq j \leq n} \frac{S_j}{\sqrt{n}} $ with comment "by convexity".

Firstly does any proof is needed here? And secondly at the beginning of page 7 exactly this relation is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a few observations:

(i) $\mathscr{S}_n(t)$ is continuous in $t$

(ii) For any integer $j\in[0,n]$, we have $\mathscr{S}_n\left(\frac jn\right)=\frac{S_j}{\sqrt n}$

(iii) For $t\in\left(\frac jn,\frac{j+1}n\right]$, the function $\mathscr{S}_n(t)$ is linear in $t$, therefore $\,\sup_{t\in\left(\frac jn,\frac{j+1}n\right]}\mathscr{S}_n(t)\,$ is achieved at either $t=\frac jn$ or $\ t=\frac{j+1}n$, hence
$$\sup_{t\in\left(\frac jn,\frac{j+1}n\right]}\mathscr{S}_n(t)=\max\left(\frac{S_j}{\sqrt n},\frac{S_{j+1}}{\sqrt n}\right).$$

Then one can conclude that
$$\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\mathscr{S}_n(t)=\max_{0\leq j\leq n}\frac{S_j}{\sqrt n}.$$